# Can I use a sub query to return cascading results?

Tags: sql

I'm not sure if this is possible, but what I am trying to do is make a list of all sub accounts that fall under their lead accounts under a certain criteria not found in the subs. The first 4 digits of the lead account determine the group, these lead accounts end with three zeroes. Then all sub accounts fall under those same 4 digits, and followed by a unique 3 digits.

The lead account contains information that is not found within the sub accounts.

To simplify, lets say I'm trying to find all "Account Numbers" whose lead accounts were "Color Code" green. The sub accounts have no color indicator.

I remember using subqueries to filter observations while showing all attributes, but could I possibly use one here? If not, do you have any suggestions?

I tried making a stab at this... really appreciate any help/advice

Comment: It would greatly help if you posted example data and the expected output.

Comment: . . . and what you've already tried.